# FileNotFoundError when save file to local host with Flask

Tags: python, flask, curl

I tried to save a video to the local folder but it not works.

This is my code:

Import some libraries:

```
import flask
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
```

The main code:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

app.config["VIDEO_UPLOADS"] = "./input/"
APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route('/video_processed', methods=['POST'])
def video_processed():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files['file']
        file.save(os.path.join(APP_ROOT,'/static/video/', secure_filename(file.filename)))
        return True

app.run()
```

And I test it with `curl`:

```
curl -X POST -F file=@"/home/data/input/IMG_6966.MOV" http:/127.0.0.1:5000/video_processed
```

Then I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/video/IMG_6966.MOV'
```

What wrong with my code?

Comment: Probably, you've checked it but just to make sure does the directory `/static/video` exists?

Comment: use ```os.makedirs(uploads_dir, exists_ok=True)``` where ```uploads_dir = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, "static/video/")``` to ensure it exists

Comment: @MoosaSaadat I didn't create the folder, now it works, thanks.

Comment: Glad to know :)